# need help understanding MFC projects

Tags: c++, mfc

can anyone please explain to me what are the files that created when i creating MFC project? what is the main file which running the dialog.
sorry if there is some mistakes i new in MFC.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you opened it as a dialog application (probably because you are not writing a document editor so did not want a "doc-vieW" and there is no option for a menu-driven application otherwise, my pet peeve with MFC):

The "App" is your application. It creates your dialog then calls DoModal() on it.

It will also create by default a stdafx.h file and fail with a "fatal error" if any of your source fails to include it. (Another total WTF).

Comment: +1, I've lost count of the amount of times I've selected MDI application and then removed the doc/view crap before I actually started coding.

Comment: A precompiled header is a total WTF?

Comment: A precompiled header should be an optional optimisation when you wish to use it. You should be allowed to statically link in code that doesn't make use of it.